# Issues with Jmeter and MongoDB: detected unknown BSON type

Tags: java, mongodb, jmeter

I would like to stress test my MongoDB 4.2 server using Jmeter.
Right now I'm not using any particular configuration, I just start the mongod instance on localhost.

I followed this guide to set up jmeter: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter.
However I'm not able to correctly run the following test:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import java.util.Arrays;

try{
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));

    Document document = new Document("_id", 7);
    collection.insertOne(document);
}
catch (Exception e){
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

due to this error:

```
2020-05-29 14:30:07,987 INFO o.m.d.cluster: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoException: org.bson.BsonSerializationException: Detected unknown BSON type "\x7b" for fieldname "^A". Are you using the latest driver version?
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:138) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) [mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.bson.BsonSerializationException: Detected unknown BSON type "\x7b" for fieldname "^A". Are you using the latest driver version?
    at org.bson.BsonBinaryReader.readBsonType(BsonBinaryReader.java:96) ~[bson-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getField(ProtocolHelper.java:147) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getOperationTime(ProtocolHelper.java:102) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.updateSessionContext(InternalStreamConnection.java:537) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:301) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.4.jar:?]
    ... 2 more
```

I tried the following MongoDB Java driver combinations (in both jmeter/lib and jmeter/lib/ext folders):

- mongodb-driver-core.jar, mongodb-driver-sync.jar and bson.jar (both version 4.0.3 and 3.12.3)
- mongo-java-driver.jar and bson.jar (version 3.12.4)

Can you help me figure out what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was running a mongod instance customized by me, and I forgot to stash the changes I made to the message format: Hence the mongo driver was not able to communicate with the server.

So the problem was my idiocy, not jmeter.